# Do Cocoa Touch frameworks not use position-independent code?

Tags: ios, xcode, dylib, ios-frameworks, fpic

I've noticed that when examining the Mach header using `otool`, Cocoa Touch frameworks never have the `PIE` flag set although I've set both "Generate Position-Dependent Executable" and "Generate Position-Dependent Code" to **NO** in Xcode. Still, this is the output I get from `otool`:

```
otool -hv framework_binary
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64   ARM64        ALL  0x00       DYLIB    16       1560   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL NO_REEXPORTED_DYLIBS
```

As you can see, the `PIE` flag isn't there. When examining an application binary, however, `PIE` is there now:

```
otool -hv application_binary
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64   ARM64        ALL  0x00     EXECUTE    24       3088   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL PIE
```

Can anybody explain this?

I've read about many people who had problems uploading their app to the App Store because a framework used by their app didn't use position-independent code (check [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3710) for an instance). This leaves me wondering how I should check if my framework uses position-independent code when `otool` never seems to report the `PIE` flag for framework binaries?! It only reports them for application binaries.

This is confusing me. I hope somebody can explain this...

Answer (score 0):

From <mach-o/loader.h>:

```
#define MH_PIE 0x200000         /* When this bit is set, the OS will
                       load the main executable at a
                       random address.  Only used in
                       MH_EXECUTE filetypes. */
```

Note: "Only used in MH_EXECUTE filetypes."

Only executables have the PIE/non-PIE distinction. Dylibs and bundles don't. They are always implicitly position-independent.

Comment: Thanks, but if dylibs are always implicitly position-independent why are some apps rejected from the App Store with Apple explicitly saying that the frameworks embedded in the app bundle aren't PIE? See here for example: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3710 Apple rejected an app because several of its embedded frameworks didn't use PIE. So it looks like frameworks can indeed be non-PIE as well, doesn't it?